# Multilista en C++ añadir elementos

Tags: c++, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Me dejaron realizar una `multilista` e insertar marcas y modelos de autos en la misma. El problema es que no logro insertar los elementos en el segundo nivel de la `multilista`. Parece que no estoy realizando correctamente la inserción del segundo nivel ya que al mostrar los modelos estos no aparecen.

Me estoy volviendo loco llevo un tiempo con ella, se los agradeceré eternamente!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class nodo_modelo {
private:
    nodo_modelo *siguiente;
    float precio;
    char *nombre;
public:
    friend class modelo;
};

class nodo_marca {
private:
    nodo_marca *siguiente;
    nodo_modelo *inferior;
    char *nombre;
public:
    friend class marca;
    friend class modelo;
};

class marca {
private:
    nodo_marca *primero_siguiente;
    nodo_modelo *primero_inferior;
public:
    marca();
    void anadir_nueva_marca(char *);
    nodo_marca * regresa_primero_siguiente();
    nodo_modelo * regresa_primero_inferior();
};

class modelo {
private:
    nodo_modelo *primero_modelo_siguiente;
public:
    modelo();
    void anadir_modelo(char *, nodo_marca *);
    void mostrar_modelos_por_marca(char *, nodo_marca *);
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    marca lista_marcas;
    modelo lista_modelos;
    char *marca = new char;
    marca = "Chevrolet";
    lista_marcas.anadir_nueva_marca(marca);
    lista_modelos.anadir_modelo(marca, lista_marcas.regresa_primero_siguiente());
    lista_modelos.mostrar_modelos_por_marca(marca, lista_marcas.regresa_primero_siguiente());
    return 0;
}


//marca
marca::marca() {
    primero_siguiente = NULL;
    primero_inferior = NULL;
}

nodo_marca * marca::regresa_primero_siguiente() {
    return primero_siguiente;
}

nodo_modelo * marca::regresa_primero_inferior() {
    return primero_inferior;
}

void marca::anadir_nueva_marca(char *nombre) {

    nodo_marca *nuevo_nodo_marca = new nodo_marca;

    nuevo_nodo_marca->nombre = nombre;

    nuevo_nodo_marca->siguiente = primero_siguiente;

    primero_siguiente = nuevo_nodo_marca;

}

//modelo
modelo::modelo() {
    primero_modelo_siguiente = NULL;
}

void modelo::anadir_modelo(char *nombre, nodo_marca * lista_marcas) {

    nodo_marca *busqueda_marca = lista_marcas;

    if(busqueda_marca == NULL) {
        cout << endl << "Aun no hay marcas dentro del sistema" << endl;
    }
    else {
        while(busqueda_marca != NULL) {
            if(busqueda_marca->nombre == nombre) {
                cout << endl << "Anadir un nuevo modelo para la marca: " << busqueda_marca->nombre << endl;

                nodo_modelo *nuevo_nodo_modelo = new nodo_modelo;
                nodo_modelo *asinar_modelo_a_siguiente = busqueda_marca->inferior;

                char *nuevo_nombre_modelo = new char;
                float precio_modelo;

                fflush(stdin);
                cout << "Ingresa el nombre del modelo: ";
                gets(nuevo_nombre_modelo);
                fflush(stdin);
                cout << "Ingresa el precio del modelo " << nuevo_nombre_modelo << ": ";
                cin >> precio_modelo;

                    busqueda_marca->inferior = nuevo_nodo_modelo;
                    asinar_modelo_a_siguiente->siguiente = primero_modelo_siguiente;
                    primero_modelo_siguiente = nuevo_nodo_modelo;

                break;
            }
            busqueda_marca = busqueda_marca->siguiente;
        }
    }


}


void modelo::mostrar_modelos_por_marca(char *nombre_marca, nodo_marca * lista_marcas) {

    nodo_marca *busqueda_marca = lista_marcas;
    nodo_modelo *busqueda_modelos;

    if(busqueda_marca == NULL) {
        cout << "Aun no hay marcas dentro del sistema" << endl;
    }
    else {
        while(busqueda_marca != NULL) {
            if(busqueda_marca->nombre == nombre_marca) {
                cout << endl << "Marca: " << busqueda_marca->nombre << endl;
                busqueda_modelos = busqueda_marca->inferior;
                while(busqueda_modelos != NULL) {
                    cout << "\t-modelo: " << busqueda_modelos->nombre << endl;
                    busqueda_modelos = busqueda_modelos->siguiente;
                }
                break;
            }
            busqueda_marca = busqueda_marca->siguiente;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando te refieres a "multilista", te refieres a lista doblemente enlazada?

Comment: No, es una lista de listas como en esta imagen https://i.imgur.com/JM4R05M.png gracias

Comment: Tu código tiene **muchos fallos**, es difícil concretar qué puede estar fallando entre todos ellos. ¿Podrías proporcionar un ejemplo más corto?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster lo voy a hacer mas legible, gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo varios problemas.
Uno de ellos es que no inicializas los nodos con un valor null. Te recomiendo que en `nodo_modelo` inicialices así:

```
private:
    nodo_modelo* siguiente = nullptr;
```

Igual en `nodo_marca` para inferior y siguiente. Y así para cualquier puntero.
Si no puedes usar un compilador semi-moderno, crea un constructor default e inicialízalos ahí.

Y eso es otra cosa, el estilo de todo este código es de un C++ muy antiguo, incluyendo por ejemplo `string.h`, `stdio` en lugar de `cstdio`, usando funciones inseguras como `gets`, strings `const char*` en lugar de `std::string` (además de asignar literales `const char*` a variables `char*` no constantes).

El problema de lógica más grave está en la función `anadir_modelo`. Cuando se encuentra la marca deseada y dentro del `while` se crea el nuevo `nodo_modelo` que se va a introducir. En la siguiente línea se crea una variable auxiliar llamada `asinar_modelo_a_siguiente`, la que se utiliza para guardar el anterior `nodo_modelo` del `nodo_marca` actual.
Pero este valor(`busqueda_marca->inferior`) puede ser null, esto te causa problemas más adelante cuando tratas de asignar `asinar_modelo_a_siguiente->siguiente` a otra cosa.
Te recomiendo que cambies

```
asinar_modelo_a_siguiente->siguiente = primero_modelo_siguiente;
```

por

```
nuevo_nodo_modelo->siguiente = asinar_modelo_a_siguiente;
```

Así se guardarían y se enlazarían correctamente los nodos de modelos.

Aunque, la asignación del nombre también es problemática. Usas `new` para instanciar un solo `char` y lo pasas como argumento para `gets()`. Esa función espera un buffer de memoria en el que pueda caber toda la cadena que vas a guardar, y sólo le das un caracter. Lo demás se escribirá en memoria que no te pertenece. Hay versiones más seguras de `gets`, pero como ya estás usando `cin`, yo diría que sería mucho más sencillo y seguro usar `std::string` cuando sea que vayas a leer input del usuario, guardar nombres de cosas, o comparar strings. Te ahorras muchos problemas.

Y detalles que no son tan importantes, como la clase llamada `marca`. En `main()` creas un objeto de tipo `marca`, y luego creas un puntero `char*` llamado "marca" que esconde la clase `marca`.